# Angular2 RC5 how to properly configure test module

Tags: unit-testing, angular

I'm updating my unit tests for Angular2 RC5. The [changelog](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes) notes the following breaking change:

> `addProviders` [is deprecated], use `TestBed.configureTestingModule` instead

But this seems to take error only when attempting to include a service in a test. Where my unit test used to do the following:

```
beforeEach(() => addProviders([
    MyService,
    MockBackend,
    ... 
]));
```

it should now configure the test module:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    providers: [
        StoryService,
        MockBackend,
        ...
    ]
});
```

But that now throws an error

> Service: MyService encountered a declaration exception FAILED
>
> Error: Cannot configure the test module when the test module has already been instantiated. Make sure you are not using `inject` before `TestBed.configureTestingModule`.

I have checked that `inject` isn't been called before the `configureTestingModule`. This doesn't affect any other component/directive tests, they seem to pass just fine. How can I resolve this error for unit testing a service with RC5? I realize that I may have to wait until the the testing documentation are updated for RC5 but any insight into possible solutions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 9):

From what I have read, you only need to init the test environment once. You can then reset the testing **module** and configure the testing module before each test:

```
beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [ GridComponent ]
        });
    });

    afterEach(() => {
        TestBed.resetTestingModule();
    });
```

The upfront configuration is:

```
var testing = require('@angular/core/testing');
var browser = require('@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing');

try {
    testing.TestBed.initTestEnvironment(browser.BrowserDynamicTestingModule, browser.platformBrowserDynamicTesting());
} catch ($error) {
    console.log("test env failure" + $error);
}
```

After reading through the code it seems configureTestingModule will call resetTestingModule internally but I like to declare it in after each for readability purposes.

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar issue and fixed it by resetting the test environment:

```
import {MyService} from './my.service';
import {inject, TestBed} from '@angular/core/testing/test_bed';
import { BrowserDynamicTestingModule, platformBrowserDynamicTesting } 
       from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing';

describe('MyService', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    // Must reset the test environment before initializing it.
    TestBed.resetTestEnvironment();

    TestBed
      .initTestEnvironment(BrowserDynamicTestingModule, platformBrowserDynamicTesting())
      .configureTestingModule({
        providers: [
          MyService
        ]
    });
  });

  it('should do something', inject([MyService], (s: MyService) => {
    let r = s.getResult();
    expect(r.length).toBe(2);
  }));
});
```

I am quite the noob when it comes to Angular 2 so I welcome corrections from more knowledgeable folks.  It seems that one should not have to reset and reinitialize the test environment in every test.  Unfortunately, it was the only way I was able to get it working.

Answer (score 4):

Stick `TestBed.configureTestingModule` inside beforeEach like so:

```
beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        providers: [
            StoryService,
            MockBackend,
            ...
]
    });
});
```

Comment: I get another error like TypeError: Cannot read property 'injector' of null now ? Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The problem arise when the TestBed is initialized outside a before each when having two spec files or more.

For example:

```
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule
      ],
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  }));
describe('AppComponent', () => {
  it('should create the app', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const app = fixture.componentInstance;
    expect(app).toBeTruthy();
  });
 });
```

will instanciate a `TestBed` beforeEach tests, not only the spec file. Hence, if you have another .spec with a TestBed and a beforeEach it will be interpreted as 2 TestBed instanciated like this:

```
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule
      ],
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  }));
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule
      ],
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  }));
describe('AppComponent', () => {
  it('should create the app', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const app = fixture.componentInstance;
    expect(app).toBeTruthy();
  });
 });
```

The error

> Failed: Cannot configure the test module when the test module has
>   already been instantiated.

will be right, since you instanciate two TestBed (but in two spec files).

To solve this problem, you must always put the `TestBed` definition (so the `beforeEach`) in a describe like this:

```
describe('AppComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule
      ],
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  it('should create the app', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const app = fixture.componentInstance;
    expect(app).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```