# Why Jasmine throws me many errors: Cannot configure the test module when the test module has already been instantiated?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I am very confused. Im learning Angular and I was writing unit tests for my service classes, with totally no problem. Today I prepared my first component spec file, and Jasmine gone crazy. When using this code:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [FooterComponent],
  });
  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(FooterComponent);
  component = fixture.componentInstance;
  span = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('span');
});
```

Jasmine throws me an error in my 31 of 146 tests:

> Error: Cannot configure the test module when the test module has
> already been instantiated. Make sure you are not using `inject` before
> `R3TestBed.configureTestingModule`.

And all the errors are in tests of service files, no single one for the component test. I am guessing it might to be related somehow with creating instance of the `fixture` or `component`. But I have no clue how. When I comment all fixture lines, like below, there is no single error:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [FooterComponent],
  });
  // fixture = TestBed.createComponent(FooterComponent);
  // component = fixture.componentInstance;
  // span = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('span');
});
```

I tried this already, with no effect:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/39410211/12603542

Also I was not able to mach similar case in SO questions. Here is an example of my service test file:

```
beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
          useClass: JwtInterceptor,
          multi: true,
        },
        { provide: AuthService, useValue: authMock },
      ],
    });

    injector = getTestBed();
    httpMock = injector.inject(HttpTestingController);
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    httpMock.verify();
  });
```

And example of complete error:

> Error: Cannot configure the test module when the test module has
> already been instantiated. Make sure you are not using `inject` before
> `R3TestBed.configureTestingModule`.
> at TestBedRender3.assertNotInstantiated (http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/node_modules/@angular/core/**ivy_ngcc**/fesm2015/testing.js:2026:1)
> at TestBedRender3.configureTestingModule (http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/node_modules/@angular/core/**ivy_ngcc**/fesm2015/testing.js:1932:1)
> at Function.configureTestingModule (http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/node_modules/@angular/core/**ivy_ngcc**/fesm2015/testing.js:1822:1)
> at UserContext. (http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/src/app/app-core/_helpers/jwt.interceptor.spec.ts:26:13)
> at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-evergreen.js:364:1)
> at ProxyZoneSpec.push.QpwO.ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js:292:1)
> at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-evergreen.js:363:1)
> at Zone.run (http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-evergreen.js:123:1)
> at runInTestZone (http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js:545:1)
> at UserContext. (http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js:560:1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was very silly. It was missing `describe` and `compileComponents`:

```
describe('FooterComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [FooterComponent],
    }).compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(FooterComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    span = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('span');
  });
});
```